# Dump SQL Server to XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-serialization

In mysql, you can use `mysqldump --xml` to dump to XML.

How do you dump a SQL Server database? Preferably to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the undocumented sp_MSforeachtable command.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'select * from ? for xml auto'
```

Comment: Where is the dump file being created, or how can I define the output? I run the command in MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express, and get a message "Command(s) completed successfully", but that's it. Thanks.